# Problema con ReportViewer C# Diseño

Tags: c#

Estoy teniendo un problema con el ReportViewer de C#.

Este es mi diseño en el Reporte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta acá todo bien, el problema es cuando lo exporto a Word, PDF, y Excel.

Este es el Excel: (No aparece la imagen del encabezado.)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el Word, Tampoco aparece la imagen. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cual es la extension de la imagen